# MIT600 Open Courseware pset4 help request

Tags: python, encryption, caesar-cipher

I've been taking the open courseware version of MIT 600 lately and I've gotten stuck on pset4.  In this pset we are experimenting with the Caesar cipher.  We had to implement functions that will do both single-layer and multi-layer encryption and decryption.  I"m struggling with the multi-layer decryption.  Here is the code for the function that handles the decryption process.

def find_best_shifts_rec(wordlist, text, start):

```
for number in range(CHARACTERS):    

    new_text = text[start:] + apply_shift(text[:start], number)

    #look for spaces in the encrypted section of text
    found_space = new_text[start:].find(' ')

    #if space occurs after out starting point
    if found_space > start:

        #if the text between the start and the space are viable words
        if is_word(wordlist, new_text[start:found_space]):
            next_check = find_best_shifts_rec(wordlist, new_text, \
                found_space)

            #if we find another list of encryption keys
            if not next_check == None:
                return [(found_space, number)].append(next_check)

    #if no spaces found
    else:

        #if from start to end of string is a word
        if is_word(wordlist, new_text[start:]):
            return [(start, number)]

#if this encryption cannot possibly contain an answer
return None
```

I'll also include the links to my full file, the pseudo-code provided by the professor, and the specifications for the pset.  I'm running into very strange issues, and whenever the code is run I always get a NoneType Error.  Thanks for any help you're willing to give!

Full file (ps4.py) and pseudo-code (ps4-pseudo.txt): https://github.com/chriswolfdesign/MIT600OCW/tree/master/master/psets/pset4

Specifications:
https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-00sc-introduction-to-computer-science-and-programming-spring-2011/unit-2/lecture-10-hashing-and-classes/MIT6_00SCS11_ps4.pdf

Comment: SO isn't a tutorial service; see the [help].

Comment: What types of questions should I avoid asking?

First, make sure that your question is on-topic for this site.

You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.

Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much.

Comment: @jonrsharpe this led me to believe that this was a reasonable question due to a relatively small scope and this is an actual problem that I am facing.  If this is not the best place to ask for assistance with online school work that I have no other places to request help, is there another website you could point me towards that may offer further assistance?  Thanks.

Comment: It's an ok question IMO. I don't know what you use as a development environment but something with an integrated debugger is absolutely crucial. I like PyCharm, but there are others. With a good debugger you can answer many of these questions on your own and learn at your speed, not ours.

Comment: Thank you James K Polk!  I've been using vim and terminal for now until I get to the point where I need something more difficult.  I'll keep playing around with the debugger and see if I can find the problem.